# Which part of the first sentence is referenced here with the "which"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, relative-pronouns, context

I have the following text:

> The role of the IS internal audit function should be established by an
> audit charter approved by the board of directors and the audit
> committee.
> Professionals should have a clear mandate to perform the IS audit
> function, which may be indicated in the audit charter.

I have a question about the last sentence:

> Professionals should have a clear mandate to perform the IS audit
> function, **which** may be indicated in the audit charter.

Does which refer to audit function or to the whole first part of the sentence?

So,

- may the IS audit function be indicated in the audit charter

or

- may it be indicated in the audit charter, that professionals should
  have a clear mandate to perform an IS audit?

Comment: It may be indicated in the charter _**that professionals HAVE a clear mandate to perform the IS audit function**_.

Comment: Ok thanks, but why did you change should have to have? Why do you emphasize it?

Comment: The charter will mention that they have it, not that they should have it. It's a condition they must fulfil in order for this charter to be approved. But I agree that this statement is ambiguous and confusing.

Comment: It seems to be the latter – the entire phrase, but is poorly worded. A requirement for audit should be much more precisely defined.

Comment: Ok thanks to both of you. I would upvote both of you if I could (reputation needed).

Comment: Also ambiguous is the role of **may** in the final sentence. Does it indicate that the conditions are allowed to be stated in the audit charter, or does it say they might possibly be found there?

Comment: which may be indicated in the audit charter refers to the entire clause.

Comment: It refers to _mandate_, a text segment, which may appear in a charter document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would re-write the last sentence in this way, risking repetition for the sake of clarity:

> Professionals should have a clear mandate to perform the IS audit function. ***The fact that they possess such a mandate*** may (*is allowed to*) be indicated in the audit charter.

If I understand it correctly, the charter will mention that they have the mandate, not that they should have it. It's a condition they must fulfil in order for this charter to be approved. The article containing this passage is mentioning the SHOULD. Why include it in this article AND in the charter? Otherwise it might have said

> ... which may ***ALSO*** be indicated in the audit charter.